# Decoding the Print Job Files

Tags: pdf, printing, cups

When i give print command ,print job file gets stored into the /var/spool/cups directory but that is in PDF format.Is there a way to decode that pdf file so that i can spy what data is there in that pdf file and accordingly take action on that user?

Answer (score 0):

> The scheduler stores job files in a spool directory, typically
>   /var/spool/cups. Two types of files will be found in the spool
>   directory: control files starting with the letter "c" ("c00001",
>   "c99999", "c100000", etc.) and data files starting with the letter "d"
>   ("d00001-001", "d99999-001", "d100000-001", etc.) Control files are
>   IPP messages based on the original IPP Print-Job or Create-Job
>   messages, while **data files are the original print files** that were
>   submitted for printing. There is one control file for every job known
>   to the system and 0 or more data files for each job.

https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-design.html

You have to search for files like `d000234` (data files, not `c000234` print control files).

You can do a `file d000234` to find information about the file format.

E.g.:

```
[root@pc cups]# file d000234 
d000234: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, Level 2
```

For this job, I've printed a PDF with my default system print dialog. Somewhere it was converted to PhostScript. Open it with any application with PostScript capabilities.

E.g.:

```
okular d000234
```

Data files are only available if you've enabled the "PreserveJobFiles" and  "PreserveJobHistory" in `cupsd.conf`.